# How to create new variable using a function?

Tags: python, database

Say I wanna create a function that can generate a new variable from the user's input and also assign the user's input as a variable's name. Are there any solutions for this?

```py
user_input = input('Assign a variable: ')

def newvariable(usr_variable):
    # code generate new variable name using the usr_variable argument.
```

Comment: Short answer: don't do that. Use a dict. See the duplicate for more details.

Comment: So we use the dict value and key as an variable and it expression?